# Dead keys stopped working in Geany

Tags: 19.10, geany, dead-keys

The last couple of days, my dead keys have stopped working in Geany. Dead keys is when you press `'` followed by `a` to make `á`. If you press `'` followed by a space you get a proper `'`. Same for `"` and `^`.

When I press `'` in Geany, the top bar sort of flashes and the cursor moves  one position to the right, but no actual character is produced (or stored, as I noticed from doing a `hexedit`).

It's just Geany. In other text processors, like LO Writer, Gedit, terminal or an HTML text field such as this, all is well. For programming, I need a *lot* of `'`s and `"`s.

I disabled all Geany plugins, exited the program, restarted, and even rebooted, but there was no change.

What could be wrong? Anyone else having this problem?

EDIT: I just realised that I have been booting a Wayland session rather than plain old Xorg for a while. Can anybody confirm that this may cause the dead keys phenomenon?

Comment: Can you add details about the way of booting _wayland_ or _old Xorg_ ?

Comment: I choose the session type from the login screen, by clicking on the cog symbol.

Comment: Ok thats an Ubuntu feature, I run Debian. My problem is about `<ctrl><shift>e` not working when `<ctrl><shift>s` is OK. But it looks like another issue. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: it depends on whether, at the login screen, I choose an "Ubuntu" session or "Ubuntu on Wayland".

The former starts plain `Xorg`; there the dead keys work as designed. Under Wayland they don't. I see that some bugs have been reported about *composing keys* in the recent past.

Having no pressing reason to use Wayland, I now switch back to Xorg.